# create jabber id on jabber.org with jabber-net libraries

Tags: c#, xmpp

Please help me ... I am new in jabber technology and I want code in c# .net to
create jabber id on jabber.org with jabber-net libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, jabber.org disabled automated creation of accounts some time ago, due to abuse. It may be re-enabled with CAPTCHA support at a later date.

Secondly, if you are developing a client for users then you should give them the choice of server to use, and help them create an account themselves. If you want your software to create accounts for them, you can use the [In-Band Registration](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html) extension. Note that this is not supported or enabled by all servers, and some servers will require you to handle CAPTCHAs or link an email address.

Since you are using XMPP then the user may already have an account - such as a Google Talk account (all Gmail accounts are also XMPP accounts).